# iOS Keyboards are not being dismissed

Tags: ios, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I have 3 text fields.

The first two allow entry using the standard keyboard, the last text field brings up a picker.

I'm having issues in dismissing the keyboards - so when the 3 text field is clicked, the picker appears however the keyboard from a previous text field remains on the screen.

Each of my text fields has a tag and I'm using the following code:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { //Keyboard becomes visible

    if (textField.tag == 1) {
        [_textField2 resignFirstResponder];
        _myPicker.hidden = true;
    }

    if (textField.tag == 2) {
        [_textField1 resignFirstResponder];
        _myPicker.hidden = true;
    }

    if (textField.tag == 3) {
        [_textField1 resignFirstResponder];
        [_textField1 resignFirstResponder];
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the textfield's delegate is set to the class this code is in.

This can be done in Interface Builder or by using:

```
[_textField1 setDelegate:self];
[_textField2 setDelegate:self];
```

in viewDidLoad

Also ensure the class conforms to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol

Comment: Hi,I've set that delegate ok. Im able to get into the textFieldDidBeginEditing method however a keyboard from one of the text fields keep appearing on top my picker. I can't figure out why

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the delegates for the text fields. You have to use `<UITextFieldDelegate>` and `self._textField1.delegate = self;`

Comment: I dragged from the textField to the files owner in IB - i presume thats the same? Also do i need to specify <UITextFieldDelegate>?